# Выделить переменную из выражения

Tags: sympy, python-3.6

Добрый день! Мне необходимо построить график сложной функции: (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 -x^2*y^3. Тут есть 2 варианта решения:
1)Просто "решать это уравнение", подбирая каждый раз новые x(в цикле от, например, -10 до 10). Этот способ очень долгий, мне нужно сделать всё это быстрее
2)Выразить y из этой функции, а потом подставлять значения. Я пробовал так сделать, но из этого графика sympy не хочет выражать y. X выражает, а y нет. Что я делаю не так?

```
>>> ex = simplify('(x**2 + y**2 - 1)^3 -x**2*y**3')
>>> solve(ex, y)
[]
```

Возможно, есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: Видимо, Y просто нельзя выразить. Зато можно выразить X и строить график по вертикали (а не по горизонтали, как это делается обычно).

Comment: вы пробовали неявный график построить, не выделяя переменную: [Is it possible to plot implicit equations using Matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2484527/4279)